# iPhone Mail Composer Appearance Change allowed?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, background-image, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I seem to remember sometime back reading that changing the appearance of the mail composer view controller was not allowed.  However, I also just tried for the first time to implement changes to my navigation bars system wide using the

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage
```

method

This changes the navigation bar in the mail composer view controller.  So, is this now allowed to make changes?  Reason I am doing the appearance call is I have a lot of navigation bars and would like to get them all set at once.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Like I said in the post, I read before that you can't make changes to mail composer view controller.

However, in iOS 5 the appearance method was introduced to set all navigation bars bar button items background image or tint using one line of code.  This will even change the mail composer view controller.  So, is it allowed now to make changes to mail composer view controller's navigation bar and uibarbuttonitems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance methods are documented and their effects are intended to be app-wide, so I see no reason why it would be a problem to use them.

Comment: Reason asking is because of this in Mail Composer Reference Document

Important The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

Comment: I believe this comment is to tell people to not reach into the view and make alterations. This text significantly pre-dates the UIAppearance functionality, so I would be it doesn't apply to this case. (It's always ultimately up to whatever reviewer you get, thought.)

Comment: I agree with you that it SHOULD be allowed, but with reviews taking almost a full two weeks for new apps...is risky.  I just don't understand why they wouldn't update the documentation.

Comment: They often don't update old docs for new functionality right away.